# Symfony 2 and projects

Tags: php, symfony, project

Let's consider I have different projects for my company. What is the best practice concerning symfony 2 ?

**1.** Add new bundle for each project in the same symfony 2 skeleton (there could be several bundles for one project: even shared bundles between differents project)

**2.** Add a new Symfony 2 skeleton for one project (there could be several bundles for one project)

if way number 1 is acceptable, is there a maximum number of bundles for one symfony 2 skeleton ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Bundle is a logical component in your website like a backend or a menue. You should build your bundles global that you can use it in new projects.

I would prefer to make more instances and build bundles that were included in your projects (vendor folder). Then you have single components and can use it in new projects.

- The advantage is that you can have different versions in different projects. Perhaps you need another version of a bundle in **Project A** and **Project B**. Thats its a bit complicated with one instance.
- When need to scale your website its better to have more instances to put it on different servers. When you have only one instance with all projects then you need everytime the complete sources.

You can build your own composer packages to update and deploy over composer.

https://packagist.org/

I think there are some more package builder.

Comment: Stolen word from my mouth. +1

Comment: thank you... to export a bundle (or bundles) so it (they) can be includable in a project you just have to get the vendor folder in the src forlder and do what exactly ?

Comment: You should work with composer and read about the composer package management.